# Grep for a string in a specific order

Tags: linux, search, grep

I need to grep a large file for words (really a string of characters) in a specified order. I also need the string to be able to contain a colon ":". For example, if the words are "apple", "banana", and ":peach", I will get the line that says, "apple cherries banana cool :peach" but not "apple  :peach cherries banana cool". I would really like to be able to have one string and not grep commands in other grep commands. I am not concerned about searching whole words only.

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression like this: "apple.*banana.*:peach"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep "apple.*banana.*:peach" file`

e.g.

```
$ echo "apple cherries banana cool :peach" | grep "apple.*banana.*:peach"
apple cherries banana cool :peach
$ echo "apple :peach cherries banana cool" |grep "apple.*banana.*:peach"
$
```

Pretty simple regex.  the "apple", "banana" and ":peach" portions are just literal strings.  The `.*` in between them is are two regex operators - the `.` will match any character, and the `*` says that the previous match can match 0 or more times.

In essence we're saying find these literal strings in this order, with any number of characters between them (including none, so even "applebanana:peach" would match.)